# Issue rendering form on mobile Bootstrap3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some this will be quite easy, I have the following web page which is exactly what I'm looking for, which aligns in the middle of the page

[image]

But when I minimize this down to see how it renders when on a mobile screen it looks like this

[image]

How on earth is someone going to write an email address in that? can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, this is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <p class="text-center">
                    <strong>Enter your email and get special information:</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email address" })
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you need to add min width for the input form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use more than just the XS (extra-small screens) grid when specifying columns
- Don't waste space on blank columns on XS screens.

Try something like:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email address" })
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /col -->
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3"></div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

- Bumped the input-group up to a full row on XS screens
- Only started making the input-group narrower on SM (small) screens